# I'm getting some issue during storage migration

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, parachain, runtime-upgrade, migration

I'm trying to trigger the storage migration on polkadot UI for our parachain. I'm trying different types to do this but getting some issues:

Type 1 : If I simply upload the wasm file from sudo > setcode, then this is coming :
[image] In this, On upper righthand blue proces will not complete.

Type 2 : I'm using scheduler pallet, But If I want to want to upload the **runtime.compact.wasm** this error is shown(Size of wasm is 4.6mb): [image]
But If I upload this runtime.compact.compressed.wasm:
[image]
This error is shown: [image]

Type 3:

Comment: Looks like you're exhausting the block limit. You can use `sudo_unchecked_weight` with value 0 - "This setting allows for a block to take an indefinite time to compute to ensure that the runtime upgrade does not fail". Take a look at this tutorial: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/forkless-upgrade/#schedule-an-upgrade

Comment: Use `compact.compressed` WASM.

Comment: @Bruno Yeah, Issue is solved by using compact.compressed wasm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try use compact.compressed.wasm instead of compact.wasm.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the way to perform runtime upgrade on parachain.

Runtime upgrade process is different in solochain and parachain. Please refer this https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/upgrade-a-parachain/